# Running angular unit test in docker - Cannot load browser RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, docker, karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher

I am having an issue running unit tests for an angular project inside a docker container. I've gone through everything I can think of but cant seem to find the issue. These tests run fine outside of docker using the same commands.

I am using node:11.8.0-alpine with the latest version of chromium

I am getting the below error:

> ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadless"!   RangeError:
>   Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at String.match ()
>       at /ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/annotation.js:30:17
>       at Array.map ()
>       at parse (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/annotation.js:29:42)
>       at Array.invoke (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:69:46)
>       at Injector.get (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
>       at module.(anonymous function) (/ng-app/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:249:64)
>       at Array.invoke (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>       at Injector.get (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
>       at module.(anonymous function) (/ng-app/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:249:64)
>       at Array.invoke (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>       at Injector.get (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
>       at module.(anonymous function) (/ng-app/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:249:64)
>       at Array.invoke (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>       at Injector.get (/ng-app/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
>       at module.(anonymous function) (/ng-app/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:249:64) 28 01 2019
>   20:34:52.281:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
>       at Server.webServer.listen (/ng-app/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:182:27)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:202:15)
>       at emitListeningNT (net.js:1290:10)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17) Cannot read property 'success' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'success' of undefined
>       at TestCommand.runSingleTarget (/ng-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/packages/angular/cli/models/architect-command.ts:242:21)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5) Segmentation fault

Below is my karma config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '/test-reports', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'junit-report.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
    },
    reporters: ['junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--disable-web-security',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--no-sandbox'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Versions:

```
"jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.2",
"@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.2",
```

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Nope, I haven't solved this.

Comment: I solved it in my case but there were several issues in the end. One of the things I changed though was `base: 'Chrome'` instead of `ChromeHeadless`. The rest was project-specific.

Comment: I have quite similar issue when use Docker: `Cannot read property 'success' of undefined at TestCommand.runSingleTarget (/ng-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/packages/angular/cli/models/architect-command.ts:242:21)` , but I don't use Chrome, I use `browsers: ['PhantomJS'],`